# Silverlight 4 in the real world - communication with server

Tags: silverlight, tcp, communication

We currently have a silverlight application (kind of a game) and we need to add more functionality which requires more interaction with the server.

We currently do all interaction by HTTP requesting data from the server and then processing on the client - works well, until we have a lot of requests or larger data amounts being returned.

Sockets in Silverlight only work on port numbers between 4502 and 4534, is there a way of making this work on the internet? A way of allowing the user to simply accept and open up a port?

What is actually blocking the port range?

========

Just to add, is this somthing that is possible in Java (http://homepages.uel.ac.uk/2795l/pages/socketap.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to achieve this is via a proxy on the server or some sort of port forwarding taking place on the server.

This can not take place on the client side by itself.

What is actually blocking the port range is the SL runtime. It does this for security reasons.

In reality making use of sockets in an Internet based application would provide some hurdles most notably the need for the firewall to allow ports 4502-4534 to be open for Silverlight communication. This is one reason that the use of sockets is used more within an Intranet application where the need to open ports is non-existent (for the most part). Since Silverlight has defined these ports as the means of communication for their runtime it at least gives the admins some control over that range; versus allowing the runtime to operate on any given number of ports.

Comment: @aaron so if the port was within the correct range, on the web what would a user see?

Comment: @Pino Not sure what you mean what would they see? If the port is in the correct range whatever communication taking place over the wire will be represented however you see fit. You can sniff the wire if you wanted...

Comment: @Aaron, would they be prompted to allow the communication. Would most user on the internet just not be able to communicate? Why do most articles state this is only useful of Intranet's

Comment: @Pino The user should not be prompted for communication as this is happening inside the runtime not within the browser per se; Most users on the Internet would most likely have those ports blocked however not all will have them blocked...added additional commentary to the answer about the Intranet reference.

Answer (score 0):

No direct way around it ( http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ncl/archive/2009/06/23/why-does-silverlight-have-a-restricted-port-range-for-sockets.aspx ).